# How to completely hide the keyboard/infrared scanner/keyevent

Tags: react-native, expo, keyboard, keyevent, infrared

I am developing a project for a Portable data terminal, which is a smartphone with Android OS and a built-in infrared scanner. The IR scanner works as follows: the scanned data (for example, the barcode number) comes in the form of text, as if entered on the keyboard.

The problem is, in React Native, I can't listen to the keyboard input event without binding to a specific input, which periodically loses focus, and accordingly, I don't receive this event

So I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to listen to the keyboard input event without binding to a specific input field for EXPO

Answer (score 0):

I build the same type of application for Android on RN and I think you need this library https://github.com/flyskywhy/react-native-usb-serialport to directly reading data from usb/serial port